# Change Color of AntD Button (background)

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am aware there are other similar topics on this, but I was wondering how to make my situation work. I have not been able to make it work with available information so far.

I am trying to modify the background color of a Text button when the mouse hovers.

If I change my backgroundColor style inline of the button, it changes the appropriate area entirely. It seems there are no way to add an :hover functionality inline (I am using TS, shows up as an error. Even though it compiles, it has no effect).

If I use a SCSS module, I can change again the whole background color. But if I change the same property with the :hover functionality, it only affects the text part (see screenshot).
I've tried targeting more specifically the ant-btn-text, but to no effect still.

Would someone have an idea? I would like to avoid creating a state variable for this.

[image: background color not changing on hover]

Edit: added portion of code and CSS as requested in comment
[image]

Comment: You should use &:hover to make the effect on hover

Comment: Tried, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Share your html and css code

Comment: screenshot added! it does work for the border color, but not the background color.

Comment: I can't do anything with images , you have any prod server like so i can inspect.

Comment: If you don't have one, simple verify that the red container's parent container i think grey should have padding to center the red container, remove the padding and make the red container width height 100% and same padding to red container. It's just a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AntD classes generally override your own css stying. You can use `!important` to override that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found it (only post it now as it was getting late local time).
So compared to my original post, the `&` parent selector was necessary, and also adding `!important` made the trick.

So in my case, having:

```
.updateButton {
    &:hover:{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

overrode the default styling.

Thank you!